# Renaming files fetched via “wget --mirror” in Bash before uploading to an Amazon S3 statically hosted area

Tags: bash, find, wget, amazon-s3

I’m trying to archive and upload an old website to statically hosted Amazon S3 area.

I was able to get the contents with `wget`, using the following command:

```
wget --mirror --no-parent --html-extension --page-requisites http://original.com
```

Then, I could replace all the links to their new URL, by:

```
ag -l original\.com -0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' \
's|original.com|old.original.com|g'
```

After this, I uploaded the website to Amazon S3 using `s3cmd sync`.

My only problem now that all the “cache-busted” assets are now access denied on Amazon. The problem is that `wget` got the files with query parameters included in their filename and I’ll need to rename them.

So I’d like to rename files recursively, in all subfolder, like:

- `style.css?ver=4.2.5.css` is renamed to `style.css`

How can I do that in Mac OS X using Bash 3.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*\?*' |\
  while read FILENAME
  do
    IFS='?'
    SPLIT_FILENAME=(${FILENAME})
    unset IFS
    echo mv "${FILENAME}" "${SPLIT_FILENAME}"
    # mv "${FILENAME}" "${SPLIT_FILENAME}"
  done
```

The `find .` indicates all the action happens in the current directory as well as child directories; feel free to change that `.` to be the full/actual filepath of what you are acting on. The `-name '*\?*'` looks for files with a question mark (`?`) in its name.

This initial/demo version also has a `-maxdepth` set to “1” so the process doesn’t go out of control on your filesystem and it uses an `echo` version of the command to show you what it would do before you run it for real.

If you run that an the output looks good, feel free to adjust the `-maxdepth 1` to something like `-maxdepth 9` or even remove that entirely and then comment out the `echo` line and uncomment the `mv` line so it looks like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*\?*' |\
  while read FILENAME
  do
    IFS='?'
    SPLIT_FILENAME=(${FILENAME})
    unset IFS
    # echo mv "${FILENAME}" "${SPLIT_FILENAME}"
    mv "${FILENAME}" "${SPLIT_FILENAME}"
  done
```

Using your test file example of `style.css?ver=4.2.5.css`, I got this output when running this script on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) system:

```
mv ./style.css?ver=4.2.5.css ./style.css
```

Looks like a good switch to me. Ran it with the real `mv` command and the file was successfully renamed to `style.css`. This would also work with files that have spaces in them such as test files like `this is my style.css?ver=4.2.5.css` and `my style.css?ver=4.2.5.css`.

Answer (score 1):

This would work on Mac OS X assuming there’s just a single `?` on the URL/original file name:

```
find . -name "*\?*" -exec sh -c 'var="{}" ; mv "{}" "${var%\?*}"' \;
```

For reference, this would work as well on Linux systems—or any system—that has the `rename` tool installed:

```
find . -name "*\?*" -exec rename "s/\?.*//" "{}" \;
```

Comment: I believe if you'd mention "brew install rename" it'd be a valid answer for OS X.

Comment: You can actually use $1, that way it'd be more elegant, no need for var.

Answer (score -1):

I'll use echo to demonstrate.

```
# echo 'style.css?ver=4.2.5.css' | cut -d? -f2-9999
ver=4.2.5.css
```

Recursion:

```
cd <yourdir>
for f in *; do
    newf=$( echo $f | cut -d? -f2-9999 )
    mv $f $newf
done
```

Assumptions: `<yourdir>` contains only files that you want changed. If not, alter the `for f in *` glob to suit. You should test the final command first with echo, i.e. replace `mv $f $newf` with `echo $f $nf` and ensure it does what you want.

Comment: Yep. I suppose I should have written 'cut -d? -f1'.